# Python enumerate built-in error when using the start parameter

Tags: python, iterable

I'm modifying some code that calls enumerate on a list declared via a list comprehension e.g.

```
self.groups = [Groups(self, idx) for idx in range(n_groups)]
```

then later:

```
for idx, group in enumerate(self.groups):
    # do some stuff
```

but when I change the enumerate call to start at the 2nd list element via the start parameter e.g.

```
for idx, group in enumerate(self.groups[1]):
```

I get an exception:

```
exceptions.TypeError: 'Group' object is not iterable
```

Could someone explain why this is?

Comment: I misread the documentation for the start parameter and I should have written "enumerate(self.groups, 1) in my original code BUT that is not what I actually intended anyway since that is the initial count value and doesn't skip any of the iterables at the start of the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem: Using an indexer with a single argument on a sequence will yield a *single* object from the sequence. The object picked from your sequence is of type `Group`, and that type is not iterable.

The solution: Use the [slice construct](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html#odbchelper.list.slice) to get a new *sequence*  of items from a specific index:

```
for idx, group in enumerate(self.groups[1:]):
    # do some stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

you're not *starting at the second*, you're trying to iterate only over the second. To start at the second item do:

```
for idx, group in enumerate(self.groups[1:]):
    # process
```

Answer (score 1):

If your sequence is large enough than consider using `islice` function from `itertools` module, because it's more memory efficient for large sequences than slicing:

```
import itertools

for idx, group in enumerate(itertools.islice(self.groups, 1, None)):
    # process
```